# I want to leave the embedded software field into something less technical day-to-day. Any ideas?

Tags: job-search, recruitment, job-change, career-switch, tech-industry

It's not that I wasn't good at it; but after a number of bad experiences working for sweat-shop/"[black company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_company_(Japanese_term))" types of businesses on out-dated tech, I'd rather take my career elsewhere due to trauma more than anything. But something I guess that's still white-collar and pays decent. Other than technical writing (which is a possibility; I've been told I'm very good at explaining things in simple language), what are some other avenues I can take and how can I get there given my experience?

Comment: It's a fantastic field.  Stick with the field and find better places to work.

Comment: No thanks. I'm done with it. I struggle to do basic things anymore having been out of it for over a year and a half and prior to that, working for nothing but these types of companies. I've lost all interest in it. All the "fantastic-ness" you speak of is in the IoT realm of which I had no interest in even beforehand and I still don't.

Comment: Ok, here's what we know about you: 1) You are reasonably good at embedded software, but hate it. 2) You are good at technical writing, but don't want us to suggest it.
So, aside from suggesting you do regular software, this is a guessing game for us. We don't know enough about you. In that case, you'd have to do some searching and find the answer yourself. [Here is a generic Q&A I started which may help you and others in this situation.](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/179916/60993)

Answer (score 1):

Just find fields where at least some of your skillset is relevant. Should be plenty. Embedded uses the same languages as other developer positions.